# Swift 2.1 Searching Contacts by E-mail in iOS 9

Tags: swift2, ios9

In the new Contacts framework there appears to be a way to search by name:

```
let predicate = CNContact.predicateForContactsMatchingName("john")

let toFetch = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey]

do {
     let contacts = try store.unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(
          predicate, keysToFetch: toFetch)

      for contact in contacts{
          print(contact.givenName)
          print(contact.familyName)
          print(contact.identifier)
      }

} 
catch let err {
        print(err)
}
```

But no apparent way to search by e-mail that I can find in the documentation or searches.

How do I search contacts by e-mail address?

These articles [here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-contacts-framework/) and [here](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ios-9-swift/9781491936689/ch04.html) have been helpful in learning the new framework but neither of these have revealed how to search by e-mail.

Comment: Did you get your question answered?

Answer (score 1):

Having the same problem, I managed to find a solution. I have solved this by fetching all the contacts and then iterating over them to find matching contacts.

The code can surely be refactored.

```
import UIKit
import Contacts

public class ContactFinder: NSObject {

    private lazy var store = CNContactStore()
    private var allContacts: [CNContact] = []
    private let keysToFetch: [CNKeyDescriptor] = [CNContactEmailAddressesKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactPostalAddressesKey, CNContactBirthdayKey, CNContactImageDataKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey]

    public func requestAccess(completion:((success: Bool, error: NSError?)->())) {

        let status = CNContactStore.authorizationStatusForEntityType(.Contacts)

        if status == .NotDetermined {
            store.requestAccessForEntityType(.Contacts, completionHandler: { [weak self](success, error) -> Void in
                if success {
                    self?.getAllContacts(completion)
                } else {
                    completion(success: false, error: error)
                }
            })
        } else if status == .Authorized {
            getAllContacts(completion)
        } else {
            completion(success: false, error: nil)
        }
    }

    public func searchForContactUsingEmail(email: String, completion:((contacts: [CNContact])->())) {
        var contacts: [CNContact] = []
        for contact in allContacts {
            let em = contact.emailAddresses

            if em.count > 0 {
                let results = em.filter({ val in
                    let ce = (val.value as! String).trimmedString.lowercaseString

                    return ce == email.trimmedString.lowercaseString
                })

                if results.count > 0 {
                    contacts.append(contact)
                }
            }
        }

        completion(contacts: contacts)
    }

    private func getAllContacts(completion:((success: Bool, error: NSError?)->())) {
        let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keysToFetch)
        request.predicate = nil
        request.unifyResults = true

        do {
            try store.enumerateContactsWithFetchRequest(request, usingBlock: { [weak self](contact, _) -> Void in
                self?.allContacts.append(contact)
                })
        } catch let e as NSError {
            print(e.localizedDescription)
            completion(success: false, error: e)
            return
        }

        completion(success: true, error: nil)
    }

}
```